# Crash with MKMapView when i use popviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mapkit, back-button

I have a problem in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `delegate` property of your map view to `nil` in `-viewDidUnload:`. This crash is occurring because the map view attempted to message it's delegate, your view controller, but it had already been deallocated once it was popped off the stack.

Apple even mentions this in passing in the [`MKMapViewDelegate` Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008204-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1).

> Before releasing an **`MKMapView`** object for which you have set a
>   delegate, remember to set that object’s **`delegate`** property to **`nil`**. One
>   place you can do this is in the **`-dealloc`** method where you dispose of
>   the map view.

They recommend nilling the `delegate` in `-dealloc`, but because of ARC, `-viewDidUnload` is the best bet moving forward.

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.mapView.delegate = nil;
    self.locationManager.delegate = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

Comment: viewDidUnload is now deprecated

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem when using objects that receive delegate calls. The problem is that after the view controller has been deallocated, it still receives a call from one of its objects, like the error message says. You need to override the `viewDidUnload` method (not to mention `dealloc` for some memory management) of your view controller, and in it you need to put something like:

```
yourMapView.delegate = nil;
yourLocationManager.delegate = nil;
```

by setting the delegates of these objects to nil, they will stop sending updates to their assigned delegates when this view controller unloads, and therefore your app will stop crashing.